# how to update local memory cache in all server instances

Tags: performance, caching, server

I have a web server cluster that contains many running web server instances. each instance cache some configurations in its local memory, the original configurations are stored in Database.

these configurations are used for every request, so the cache may necessary for performance reason.

I want to provide an admin page, in which, the administrator can change the configurations. how do I update all the cache in every server instance?

now I have two solutions for this:

1. set an expire time for the cache.
2. when administrator update the configuration, notify each instance via some `pub/sub` mechanism(e.g. use redis).

for solution 1, the drawback is the changes can not take effect immediately.
for solution 2, I'm wondering, if the pub/sub will have impact on the performance of the web server.

which one is better? or is there any common solution for this problem？

Comment: A, well known "there are two hard problems in software engineering: naming things, cache invalidation and off-by-one errors".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another drawback of option 1 is that you'll periodically hit your database unnecessarily.

If you're already using Redis then option 2 is a good solution.  I've used it successfully and can't imagine how there could be a performance impact just because you're using pubsub.

Another option is to create a cache invalidation URL on each website, e.g. /admin/cache-reset/, and have your administration tool call the cache-reset URL on each individual server.  The drawback of this solution is that you need to maintain a list of servers.  If you're not already using Redis it could just be the simple/practical/low-tech solution that you're looking for.